# Cross-platform IDE alternative to MS Visual Studio - other than Eclipse CDT

Tags: java, c++, ide, cross-platform, c

I program on Linux (CentOS), OS X and Windows, primarily in C and C++. I've used Eclipse CDT on CentOS, and it's decent, but I find I prefer Visual Studio.

The issues I have with Eclipse CDT are that it still doesn't fully support C++ 11 (code that compiles using g++ with no errors or warnings is marked as wrong in the IDE). Also, find and replace, or just find, doesn't work as well as Visual Studio.

Requirements:

- Find and replace works like Visual Studio on Windows
- Autocomplete
- C++ 11 and C++ 14 syntax support
- Integration with Mono C#
- Generating UML class diagrams
- Code Folding
- Possible integration with GNU g++
- Possible integration with Java
- Full debugging capability
- Cross-platform on Linux, OS X and Windows

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) I've edited your question accordingly, so it should still match your intent.

Comment: @CalvT Thanks for the suggestion, I found g2crowd.com has reviews.

Comment: I am a little late to the party, but take a look at [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) as a possible alternative that is Free, Open Source & Cross Platform.

### Your feature requests

- Find and replace works like Visual Studio on Windows - *Find and replace works really well and includes: Find in Current File, Open Files, Project Files, Workspace Files or any path with recursive and filename patterns*.
- Autocomplete - *Yes for C/C++ & Fortran not sure for other languages*
- C++11 and C++14 syntax support - *Yes*
- Integration with Mono C# - *Not directly but can be added as an external toolchain*
- Generating UML class diagrams *Has support to invoke Doxygen*
- Code Folding *Yes for lots of languages, includes folding comments*
- Possible integration with GNU g++ *Built in*
- Possible integration with Java *You can add*
- Full debugging capability *Yes*
- Cross-platform on Linux, OS X and Windows *Yes* ***all of them***

### Additionally:

- Plug in Architecture
- Support for multiple compilers & tool chains or you can add your own
  [image: Compilers List]
- cppcheck intetration
- Threaded Search
- Link to available help files
- To Do List
- Syntax Highlighting and Code Folding for multiple langages:
  [image: Syntax List 1][image: Syntax List 2]
- Standard & Custom per Language abbreviations lists - *allows you to type your abbreviation and press Ctrl-J to replace with a code fragment, with cursor placement and prompts for values.*
- Source formatter with 14 styles & custom
- Project templates/wizards, including custom.
  [image]
- Code Statistics for C/C++, Java, Python, Perl, ASM, Pascal & Matlab
  [image]
- Multiple custom keyboard shortcuts profiles
- Spell Checker for comments & strings, with suggestions & thesaurus.
- Code Refactoring
- Scripting - including adding menu items to invoke scripts and scripts to run on startup.
- Cscope, BlackDuck, Koders, etc. integration
- Regex tester

Comment: Thanks Steve! I like the looks of it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [JetBrains CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) may meet almost all of your requirements. It is often not gratis, though.

You might also want to have a look at the [C++ IDE comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is suppose to be the "Visual Studio" of Mac and Linux. There is also [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio). Xamarin was bought up by Microsoft within the past year, and is going to be Microsoft's cross platform development solution.

Comment: You might want to google visual studio code, this may be what Xamarin Studio became.

Comment: Nope, those are two different things. Visual Studio Code is a glorified code editor like Notepad++.

Comment: Quote "Visual Studio Code is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and OS X. It is free and open-source, and includes support for debugging, embedded Git control, syntax highlighting, intelligent code completion, snippets, and code refactoring."

Comment: Your right "Code Editor" not IDE. Atom, Notepad++, Brackets, all code editor, but not an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

**Qt Creator**

Qt Creator is a very good (and portable) C/C++ IDE in my experience. Its code-completion and code navigation capabilities are on par with Visual Studio.

I'm not sure how well it handles the other languages mentioned (C# and Java), but if C/C++ is the main language I think it's worth giving it a shot.

[Download page for Qt Creator](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-12)

Answer (score 1):

#### jucipp

Jucipp (Juicy-C++, get it?) is a" lightweight, platform independent C++ IDE with support for C++11, C++14 and C++17 features".

I just noticed this project, so I can't vouch for its quality, but it's quite popular on GitHub, with over 700 stars at this time. It has had official releases for 2 years now already, with the latest release being 1.3.2, just under a month ago - so it seems to be at least maintained if not actively developed.

Its feature set is not as broad as Eclipse CDT (e.g. no Mercurial support); specifically, it's supposedly clang-focused.

Read more and download it from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cppit/jucipp).

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this question 4 years ago I was unaware of JetBrains products. I have used JetBrains products for over a year and the present the same UI on all operating systems. That said JetBrains may have been involved with the recent security hacks in the US Federal government sites so buyer beware.

Another option is Eclipse which is open source. While it is primarily used for Java, Eclipse CDT is a C++ IDE.