# Linux alternative to MS Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: linux, c++, ide

So I want to write a C++ program for Linux which works on a very low level, to the point where VM just doesn't cut it.

But I'm really used to writing C++ using Visual Studio, but as you know Visual Studio is not available in Linux.

So I'm looking for a Linux alternative which allows me the same kind of project management as Visual Studio does, as well as giving me a simple easy building process, and easy debugging, all in the same fashion as VS.

Anyone knows a replacement that would work for me?

Comment: Try reading [Cross-platform IDE alternative to MS Visual Studio - other than Eclipse CDT](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33792/cross-platform-ide-alternative-to-ms-visual-studio-other-than-eclipse-cdt); and of course, also have a look at [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-06/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers).

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is available for all major platforms. It quickly gained popularity in 2017 and is [the most popular editor on Stack Overflow in 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/). It's technically an editor, not an IDE but it allows you to manage projects, develop and debug easily just like Visual Studio. It also has support for almost any languages that you can imagine

Answer (score 1):

IDEs are a very personal choice for developers and the decision to stick with one shouldn't be made casually. If you like Visual Studio try Visual Studio Code. It's available on popular Linux distros.

However, if you are looking something *not* Microsoft, here are a few really good options:

https://www.eclipse.org/

https://netbeans.org/

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ (my personal favorite for many programming languages - it's not free but has plugins for every language)

https://atom.io/

http://www.codeblocks.org/

https://www.sublimetext.com/

http://www.aptana.com/  (based on Eclipse)

It can be a major investment in time but, finding the right IDE for you is totally worth trying a few of these options.

Good luck.

** Edit: Thanks @phuclv - I mixed up Visual Studio Code with Visual Studio. Accurate info is important. **

Comment: Visual Studio isn't available for any non-Windows platforms. Visual Studio Code is a completely different product. And Visual Studio for Mac is actually just a renamed Xamarin IDE and has nothing to do with Visual Studio anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers here, both of which I agree with and upvoted .

I will confuse you by saying that in industry we alamost always use Eclipse. But, at home, I use Visual Studio Code. Both of them are great with multiple languages (as is NetBeans).

Like @CheddarMonkey (great name) said, "`It can be a major investment in time but, finding the right IDE for you is totally worth trying a few of these options.`". You will be using the IDE for years, so try a few and see what suits you best.

Those are all cross platform, but, as you specify Linux, I will add another suggestion.

The classic Kde IDE is [Kdevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/), note that it can can also support Python & PHP (Visual Studio code supprts those, plus JS (that I use), plus a whole slew of others).

[image]

Take a look at the [features](https://www.kdevelop.org/features).

It is  rock solid and well supported, with [1,100+ questions on S.E](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=kdevelop) and its own [forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=218).

Don't KDE? If you Gnome, then read [KDevelop? What about gnome?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=337369) on the Ubuntu forums - and DuckDuckGO for more.

Finally, although there are great suggestions from the others, you might want to consider running each of them through the AlternativeTo site. I'll start you off with [free linux alternatives to KDevelop](https://alternativeto.net/software/kdevelop/?license=free&platform=linux)

Btw, since you have such a lot of choices, could you please post (maybe update your question) to let us know which you chose, and why. The more info you give about your decision, the more that you will help oothers who visit this question in future - just as you have been helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I can't believe no one has mentioned [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools)

It is truly available for all major platforms (exact same environment on Linux, Windows, Mac, others); indeed, Qt is the premier cross-platform development environment.

It features a code editor supporting C++, JavaScript, Python and other languages. It features code completion, syntax highlighting, and refactoring.

It also features integration with version control, a built-in UI designer, debugging, and build management.